# Python program that prints this pattern with n rows, where n is input by the user. In this example output, n = 6

Tags: python, python-3.x

I tried to workout some code but I am not able to meet the expected output. The expected output looks like this :

[image: output]

Here is what I've tried :

```
n = int(input())
for row in range(1, n + 1):    
   print(' ' * (n - row), end = '')    
   for col in range(row, 0 , -1):
       print(col, end = ' ')
   print()
```

Comment: please avoid posting links to images, add expected outputs into the question preferably as text

Comment: And your current code does what…?

Comment: Hint: the `print()` that adds a newline is only called once after the loop…

Comment: it does this 
https://imgur.com/a/NoOmZDd

Comment: @ deceze i have changed the print statement and in the col loop body.

Comment: Then think about why your upper lines may not have enough spaces compared to the lower lines…

Comment: instructions unclear got my compiler stuck in explorer.

Comment: How many characters are in the line `6 5 4 3 2 1`? How many spaces are you adding with `' ' * (n - row)` before `1` on the first line…?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the printout of your code (when the user inputs `6`):

```
     1 
    2 1 
   3 2 1 
  4 3 2 1 
 5 4 3 2 1 
6 5 4 3 2 1
```

As you can see, there are not enough spaces at the top. The first row now has `5` spaces, but it needs another `5` spaces to push the `1` all the way to the right. The second row has `4` spaces but needs another `4`. In fact, you need to double the number of spaces at the start of each row. So just multiply the number of desired spaces by two:

```
n = int(input())
for row in range(1, n + 1):    
   print(' ' * 2 * (n - row), end = '')    
   for col in range(row, 0 , -1):
       print(col, end = ' ')
   print()
```

Do you see the `* 2` that I added to your code? The printout is now

```
          1 
        2 1 
      3 2 1 
    4 3 2 1 
  5 4 3 2 1 
6 5 4 3 2 1
```

which is what you want.

There are other ways to get what you want. For example, rather than adding `* 2` to that line of code, you could replace the single space with two spaces:

```
print('  ' * (n - row), end = '')
```

That also works and looks better.